# WebPack require context from list in external json file

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, bundle, manifest.json

I have `build_modules.json` file, which contains information about modules should be required by WebPack, for example:

```
[
    'module.superman',
    'module.superwoman',
    'module.spiderman',
    'module.wolverine'
]
```

So, I need to require all those modules only once to compile everything to single bundle:

```
var _modules = require('./build_modules.json');

_modules.forEach(function(_module){
    require('./modules/' + _module);
});
```

Everything works pretty fine, but if I am having some other files in `./modules/` folder than listed in `build_modules.json`, all of them are included to bundle due to WebPack core mechanism, though, they are not required and will never be used in current build. I need to forcely exclude those excess files from bundle because, in praxis, my `./modules/` folder contains over 200 different modules and only modules that are in `build_modules.json` should be included to current bundle.

*Maybe I can do this with some plugin, or maybe inside of `webpack.config.js` file to construct a list of needed modules and require them with node.js, then put all that stuff to WebPack as a precompiled context?*

Comment: What's the problem with the answer you already got from Pawel?

Comment: I still believe that there is a solution. That is very stupid, from the point of webpack, not to have any solution to create a context manually with a manual list of modules. May be there is some plugin or module, which allows to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had got similar problem. Webpack does not allow to create dynamic requires. It takes all modules before the code is executed.
But you can use `require.context` to load necessary modules according to some `regexp` rules. You can read more here: [webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html)

You can name modules, that you want to load in some specific way, eg. `module.*` and use `require.context("./modules/", false, /^module\..+$/)`.
Then all modules that begin with `module.` will be required before the code execution.

I remember that I was struggling with that for a couple of hours and that was the best solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

**In case you need just to execute your modules**

You need to set `entry` property in webpack config. This property accepts array as value of files to include in bundle.

```
// webpack.config.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const getModulePath = module => path.resolve(__dirname, './relative/path/to/modules/directory', module);

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('./your.json');
const entries = JSON.parse(fileContent).map(getModulePath);

module.exports = {
  // all entries will be built during one build process
  // if you need you can split each entry to separate config file
  entry: {
    bundle1: entries, // build modules from JSON file to single bundle
    bundle2: [ './file1', './file2' ], // build static modules to single bundle
    bundle3: './sindle/file', // "classic" build
    all: [ ...entries, './file1', './file2', './sindle/file' ], // you can combine everything to 1 bundle
  },
};
```

**In case you need to export something from your modules**

Unfortunately webpack's entry as array won't help you because it will export only last file in array.

I didn't heard something about such plugins that can combine certan files and use it as entry point. But you can create such file by yourself.

```
// webpack.config.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// saving tmp file location
const pathToCreatedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, './path/to/created/file');
// implement fn to get relative path to modules from tmp file
const getModulePath = module => path.relative(pathToCreatedFile, path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  './relative/path/to/modules/directory',
  module,
));

// read json
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('./path/to/your.json');
// prepare modules for tmp file
const entries = JSON.parse(fileContent)
  .map(item => ({
    name: item.slice(7),
    relpath: getModulePath(item),
  }));

// here generate import directive for each module. I used `import * as modules_name from 'path';` format
// you can choose any
const importsString = entries.map(({ name, relpath }) => `import * as ${name} from '${relpath}';`).join('\n');
// here generate exports from tmp file. It contain of all imports
const exportsString = `export {${entries.map(({name}) => name).join(',\n')}};`;
// and here just concatenate imports ad exports
const content = [
  entries.map(({ name, relpath }) => `import * as ${name} from '${relpath}';`).join('\n'),
  `export {${entries.map(({name}) => name).join(',\n')}};`,
].join('\n');

// and save tmp file content to fs
fs.writeFileSync(pathToCreatedFile, content);

module.exports = {
  // and here use saved tmp file path as entry point
  entry: pathToCreatedFile,
};
```

After you import builded bundle it will return plain object with your modules. You can use `Object.values` or similar to get your dependencies as array.

And another aproach, you can format `exportString` to export array of imports.

I used `import * as name from ...` format to show you more common way to create file. If you don't have any default exports or you have only default export it's better to use `export * from ...` or `export {default as name} from ...` formats respectively.

Comment: You missed the _then put all that stuff to WebPack as a precompiled context?_ (especially, the _context_ keyword). I do not need a separate file with modules because I need to **require them all in a main file of my project**. To be more particular, saying `var marvel = [];` and then, in cycle, `marvel.push(require('./modules/' + _module));`. If following your suggestion, I can't require all the modules that way to the very one array `marvel`. They will unlikely be separated from each other, even though placed into a single final destination bundle.